# Is there any way to override a WordPress template with a plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to make a landing page. If plugin detects some GET or POST requests it should override wordpress theme and show its own.

It would work somehow like that:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'myPluginAction'){
    /* do something to maintain action */
    /* forbid template to display and show plugin's landing page*/
}
```

I'm familiar with WP Codex, but I don't remember if there is any function to do that. Of course, I googled it with no results.

Thanks for any ideas in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need the hook [`template_include`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L46). It doesn't seem documented in the Codex, but you can find more examples here in SO or in [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=template_include)

### Plugin file

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Landing Page Custom Template
 */
add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_13997743_custom_template' );

function so_13997743_custom_template( $template )
{
    if( isset( $_GET['mod']) && 'yes' == $_GET['mod'] )
        $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'my-custom-page.php';

    return $template;
}
```

### Custom Template in Plugin folder

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom Plugin Template
 * File: my-custom-page.php
 *
 */

echo get_bloginfo('name');
```

### Result

Visiting any url of the site with **`?mod=yes`** will render the plugin template file, e.g.: `http://example.com/hello-world/?mod=yes`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to be the perfect solution.

Answer (score -1):

> you need to create a folder '/woocommerce/' inside your plugin directory, inside woocommerce you need to add a folder say, for email 'emails' and put the required template inside '/emails/' to override. just copy paste this code in the main.php of your plugin.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Plugin
 */

function myplugin_plugin_path() {   
  // gets the absolute path to this plugin directory 
  return untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ); 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template', 10, 3 ); 
function myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {

  global $woocommerce;  
  $_template = $template; 
  if ( ! $template_path ) $template_path = $woocommerce->template_url; 
  $plugin_path  = myplugin_plugin_path() . '/woocommerce/'; 
  // Look within passed path within the theme - this is priority 
  $template = locate_template( 
    array( 
      $template_path . $template_name, $template_name 
    ) 
  );

  // Modification: Get the template from this plugin, if it exists 
  if ( ! $template && file_exists( $plugin_path . $template_name ) ) 
    $template = $plugin_path . $template_name;  

  // Use default template 
  if ( ! $template ) 
    $template = $_template; 

  // Return what we found 
  return $template; 
 }
?>
```

for reference [template override using plugin](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/)