# Wordpress plugin development to project plugin in Frontend

Tags: frontend, wordpress

I'm quite new to wordpress plugin development and I make a plugin which is not wordpress content related, like all the data are stored in custom mysql tables.

I already done the following steps:

I've been creating my plugins backend like registering admin pages which are interacting with my custom mysql tables(data creation, update, delete etc.)

Now I would like to project administrated data on my frontend and here comes the issue. How to do this?

as I understand from wiki: shortcodes would not work in my case because I would like to use url query strings

the url would look like `wordpress/?my_plugin.php&id=123&..`

I read about virtual pages but I can not get out a suitable workaround.

How to do this?

my plugin structure

```
-my_plugin
--admin
---models
---views
---my_plugin_admin.php
--site
---models
---views
---my_plugin_frontend
--my_plugin.php //acts as main controller
```

than in my_plugin.php

```
class MyPlugin {
    static function install() {
        // do not generate any output here
    }
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('MyPlugin', 'install'));
$collections = new MyPlugin();
if (is_admin()) {
    include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'admin/my_plugin_admin.php' );
} else {
    include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'site/my_plugin_frontend' );
}
```

than in my site controller I try to fetch the required datas inside of a class

```
define('PLUGIN_SITE_ROOT', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

class Frontpage {

    public function __construct() {

        //init requierd 
    }

    //and gather data functions calling model when is needed from /site/models

}

new Frontpage();
```

and more importent would to initite this plugin on the page wher is needed!!

Comment: you could start by making an administration page as a normal wp page. Go to pages, add new, and assign it a custom template. Then within that custom template you can pretty much do anything you want. Your custom plugin is basically just php so you're not really limited. you don't need to rely on shortcodes unless you want elements of your module to appear within posts or other places that could be entered through the wysiwyg. So copy page.php, replace the whole top comment with Template name: Custom Admin then upload to your server template directory. It will be available as a template now

Comment: yes I done that but how do I project my plugins variales in that custom page?

Comment: So long as your plugin is active you should be able to access any property of your module's class or any functions defined in the files. It also depends on how you are trying to access them. Ajax has a different process. But mostly you can figure any module is essentially just an included file in php. Your module's config can instantiate a class if you're using classes. You would have to post what you have tried so we can see what went wrong

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13999632/1287812)